# Angular cleaning up build files?

Tags: angular

Angular generates a lot of trash from a `.ts` file.

```
app.component.js
app.component.spec.js.map 
app.component.js.map
app.component.spec.ts     
app.component.spec.js
```

Is there any simple way to delete of that, a lot of build systems support `clean`,

```
make clean
git clean
```

How do you do this in angular

### My test case.

1. Download [Angular's Hero Demo toh-3](https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt3/toh-pt3.zip)
2. Unzip it
3. Jump into the directory
4. Run `npm install`
5. Run `npm start`

Now from the `main.ts` you now have `main.js` and `main.js.map`

In my own project, where I'm working along with the angular-cli, I actually have `.spec` files too.

Answer (score 3):

Check this method

I make build: ng build --env prod which will write it under dist folder
Then I run ng serve and my build is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Angular CLI? If so, by default it no longer generates all of these "trash" files.

Comment: This should be comment. But, by any means I updated the question with my test case and example.

Comment: I'm on the Angular doc team and as far as I know, the Tour of Hero's tutorial is still using systemjs and manually creating the files. It has not yet been updated to using the Angular CLI. If you are using the latest version of the CLI for your own project, you should not be seeing the .js and .map files.

Comment: You're actually correct (though this should still be a comment :) ). I started this a few days ago, and I did so from the github seed, https://angular.io/guide/setup Be great if that was updated at least.

Comment: But is this not then the answer to your question? And I completely agree ... we have updating the TOH to the CLI on our todo list.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of trivia, the Tour of Hereos demo was not created (yet) with the Angular CLI but it is set to change. To remove the build files, I've been using this.

```
find ./src/ -name '*.ts' -print0  |
  sed -z -e's/\.ts$/.*$/' |
  xargs -0 -I pattern find ./src -type f -not -name '*.ts' -regex pattern -exec rm {} \;
```